# Do I need second domain controller when we use AzureAD hybrid setup?

Tags: windows, domain-controller, cloud, entra-id

The subject wraps up my story pretty straight - Do I need second domain controller when we use AzureAD hybrid setup?
We have one domain with only one domain controller what is on-prem, and its AD is synced to AzureAD service.
As what as I know from my experience for best practice is to use at least two domain controllers so the question is - if we use AzureAD, is it worth looking at second DC? What I mean is, AAD is not replacing domain controller, right?

Sorry for such a simple question, I'm new to cloud and would be grateful for your understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Do you need a second domain controller? Yes.

Does Azure AD replace your domain controller or replace the need for a second domain controller? No.

Comment: Thank you I got the point, now I should look for a best option where to host it. We have both AWS and Azure. On Azure for a VM to host it would be as much as 200$ per month what seems a bit expensive to me for a small 100 user company

Comment: 200 for 100 users? the company makes a million of dollar and you speculate about some Promille?